# python regular expression split can't into ('ca', "n't")

Tags: python, regex, nlp

Disclaimer: This question is based on one of the questions in the book ["Natural Language Processing with Python"](http://www.nltk.org/book/).

I wish to:

1) split words with a "n't" to separate words: such as "can't" to ("ca", "n't"),

2) Also match words such as "the" to "the"

I got the right answer, but not sure why. In particular, why does the end-of-line anchor ($) make the "\w+" less greedy and stops it from matching the "n"?

```
import re
words = ["can't", 'dog']

#Not the write answer b/c \w+ matches the "n"
[re.findall(r"(\w+)(n't)?", w) for w in words] # [[('can', ''), ('t', '')], [('dog', '')]]

#Somehow end of line anchor stops \w+ from matching 'n'
[re.findall(r"(\w+)(n't)?$", w) for w in words] #[[('ca', "n't")], [('dog', '')]]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Because `+` is greedy. tr `(\w+?)(n't)?`

Answer (score 2):

Using `$` means that the expression *must* go all the way to the end of the line (or in this case, the end of the string).  (Note that in that expression the `n't` is optional but the `$` isn't.)  The `\w+` can match the "n" but not the apostrophe.  If the `\w+` matched "can", then in order to get all the way to the end of the line, the rest of the expression `(n't)?$` would have to match the rest of the string `"'t"`, which it doesn't.

When you don't use the `$`, the expression isn't forced to match the whole string.  Then `\w+` can match `"can"`, and it just stops there without matching any more.

Comment: I understand now. Because the $ is not optional, the regex engine must backtrack the \w+ after hitting the "'" until there is an overall match to reach the end of the line. In this case that means backtracking from "can" to "ca" so that "n't" can match. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`+` is greedy by default. so `\w+` in this `(\w+)(n't)?` regex matches greedily  upto the `n` in the string `can't` and then it won't backtrack to get the result of `can't` because you make the next pattern that is `(n't)?` as optional.

In-order to avoid this, you need to add a non-greedy quantifier `?` next to the `+` symbol like

```
(\w+?)(n't)?
```

So that it would stop consuming the word characters using this `(\w+)` pattern once it finds a substring like `n't` .

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rF1sU7/4)

```
>>> words = ["can't", 'dog']
>>> [re.findall(r"(\w+?)(n't)?\b", w) for w in words]
[[('ca', "n't")], [('dog', '')]]
```

Adding a word boundary next to the optional group will give you the desired output because we declared the previous pattern that is `\w+?` as non-greedy and we also make the following `(n't)` as optional. So it splits up the input string. After adding the word boundary `\b` next to the optional group, it ensures that there must be a word boundary follows the matched string.

Comment: That works in the regex demo. But in Python it does not give the desired result:
    re.findall(r"(\w+?)(n't)?", "can't") #[('c', ''), ('a', "n't")]

Comment: is this `[('ca', "n't")], [('dog', '')]` your expected output?

Comment: Yes! What was your Python line that generated it?

Comment: no other choice other than adding the end of the line anchor or word boundary. See https://regex101.com/r/rF1sU7/7 or `(\w+?)(n't)?\b` https://regex101.com/r/rF1sU7/8

Answer (score 1):

```
(\w+)(?=n't|$)(n't)?
```

You can also try this.Use this with `re.findall`.See demo.Grab the captures.

https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/30